# how can i call select box on change while changing select value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

I am having a select box like this

```
 <select class="cars" onChange="carName()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If am changing dropdown values `carName` function is calling and working as expected. If suppose I change the value using jQuery like this

```
$('.cars').val('Audi');
```

I want that `carName()` function to be called.How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) event programmatically

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

Also, value is case sensitive, so use correct value. use `audi` instead of `Audi`

*Code*,

```
$('.cars').val('audi').trigger('change');
```

Also since you are using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) bind event using it like

```
$('.cars').on('change', carName); //Or, $('.cars').change(carName);
```

```js
function carName() {
  alert('In carName function');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cars').val('audi').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="cars" onChange="carName()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to add `.change()`

```
$('#cars').change(function() {
 carName();
});
```